# display two right parentheses for negative numbers in my cube

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, mdx, cube

I'm getting two right parentheses for negative numbers in my cube for all measures.  Can't figure out how to fix it:

The results looks like:

jan 2009  ($4,000))
feb 2009   $1,000
mar 2009  ($5,000))

It displays this way in all front-end tools (ProClarity, VS browser, Excel).

Answer (score 1):

The format for negative numbers is a configurable item in Windows.  In Win7 that's done by Control Panel + Region and Language, Format tab, Additional Settings button.  The settings you select are written to the registry.  Selecting a format with two trailing parentheses isn't an option it lets you enter, suggesting that the registry is messed up.  It's got a Reset option, try that first.  Ask more questions about this at superuser.com